# How to convert array of objects to array of strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have data that looks like this:

```
[{"id":"Bloomberg","selected":true,"displayName":"Bloomberg"}, {"id":"some_other_company","selected":true,"displayName":"some_other_company"}]
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
["Bloomberg", "some_other_company"]
```

and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'works', 'string'), '\\"', '"')
    FROM <table>
    ...
```

Is there an elegant way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it would look something like the following, and you can achieve similar using Redshift:

```
SELECT json_agg(json_extract_array_element_text(obj, 'displayName')) AS display_names
FROM (
    SELECT json_array_elements(your_json_column::json) AS obj
    FROM your_table
) subquery;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html